# How to use icons from ttf file

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

We have Lean Symbol ttf file. We want to use that in our application. We have added that one in our application but don't know how to use it. Like other i.e. glyphicons ttf we use class for accessing its icon representation etc. How I can do w/ this?

We have LeanSymbol.ttf file. When I open it by double click I get this one http://snag.gy/Rwi9Q.jpg
We want use these icon in our application but don't know how to access that icons.

Comment: Can you proved some more detail. A URL for Lean Symbol ttf. Also it is helpful if you include any code from your attempts in your question.

Comment: I have just added @font-face{src:'my ttf file path}. Don't have an idea how to use its symbols.

Comment: check out my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Go to ForntSquirrel's [web font generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

Upload your font.

Download your kit.

The zip that you download has all the fonts in web format and gives you some great examples of how to use them.

You might want to consider using [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), which is awesome.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) also includes [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) as one of their components.

Comment: But, be aware that for virtually all modern browsers [you now only need the `woff` version](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff), and that SVG fonts have been abandoned as a thing, and [are no longer supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20font). Font squirrel was necessary in the past, these days you can just convert the `ttf` to `woff` yourself and then write a super simple @font-face rule (loading only a single file, so none of the bullet-proof syntax is necessary anymore) in your CSS to load it in.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to convert the font into a web font.  You can then add the generated font-face css to your stylesheet.